# Automate microsoft forms creation

Tags: forms, azure, automation

I'm looking for options to automatically create Microsofts forms pro.

For that, I have found [this developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/forms-pro/create-survey) but the only option to create a form I see there is to do it manually.

[image]

The is also this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/forms-pro/developer/reference/entities/msfp_question

But it seems to me from there that it is to interact with existing forms instead that for creating new forms:

[image]

I'm Comparing this to [google forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms), where is pretty clear that it is possible to create forms from scrash:

[image]

Is there any option to create Microsft forms pro in a similar way than google forms?

Comment: The documentation says that "POST [org URI]/api/data/v9.0/msfp_surveies" is for creating new forms - did you overlook that - or are you having a problem with understanding how to use it? Are you making raw HTTP requests or are you using the `Microsoft.Xrm.*` client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/forms-pro/developer/reference/entities/msfp_survey) to learn more about automating the process of Survey creation using Microsoft Forms Pro.

[image]

You can use ***msfp_survey*** for creating a new Survey in Microsoft Forms Pro.
You can also use the ***msfp_surveyresponses*** for retrieving responses of a survey automatically. 
For more detailed information on how to use these Entity References in Microsoft Forms Pro, visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/forms-pro/developer/forms-pro-reference).